# I need to block some videos (inside Youtube app) and sites (inside Chrome or another browser) using keyword

Tags: networking, firewall

example: I want to block pages/videos where the content/title contains the word "fish". How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Youtube only uses HTTPS connections so you can not access content of network connections outside of the Youtube app. For content filtering accessing the transferred content is crucial, so filtering Youtube content in Youtube app is impossible on unrooted devices.

Comment: @Robert cant we use something like a firewall over vpn? i might be wrong... idk if im able to convey what i want to

Comment: A firewall can only block connections on a per host basis. For YouTube this would mean allow everything or block everything. HTTPS connections are designed to preserver integrity and confidentiality, and YouTube app checks server authenticity, that means HTTPS is your enemy, a well designed enemy you can't defeat on an unrooted device.